# How to keep the command handler clean of querying logic? (CQRS and MediatR)

Tags: c#, .net, cqrs, clean-architecture, mediatr

The problem that I am dealing with is how to keep my controllers free of querying logic that really should be an Infrastructure rather that Application concern.

Down below is an example of Command and CommandHandler. I am using MediatR by the way.

As you can see, the Command contains some filters (which I think is ok, that does not violate CQRS) but the Command Handler has too much logic in it. I am not sure that is something that the handler has to deal with.

*GetMatchesCommand*

```
public class GetMatchesCommand : IRequest<IEnumerable<MatchDto>>
{
    public Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> TimeInterval { get; set; }
    public Guid? Location { get; set; }
    public Guid? Team { get; set; }
    public Guid? Player { get; set; }
}
```

*GetMatchesCommandHandler*

```
public class GetMatchesCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<GetMatchesCommand, IEnumerable<MatchDto>>
{       
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MatchDto>> Handle(GetMatchesCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Expression<Func<Match, bool>> filterExpression = default;
            
        // Build the filter expression

        // Filter by interval
        if (request.TimeInterval != null)
            filterExpression.ConcatAnd(
                m => m.StartTime >= request.TimeInterval.Item1
                && (m.StartTime + m.Duration) <= request.TimeInterval.Item2);

        // Filter by team
        if (request.Team != null)
            filterExpression.ConcatAnd(
                m => m.Team1Id == request.Team
                || m.Team2Id == request.Team);

        // Filter by player
        if (request.Player != null)
            filterExpression.ConcatAnd(
                m => m.Team1.Players.Any(p => p.Id == request.Player)
                || m.Team2.Players.Any(p => p.Id == request.Player));

        var query = _dbContext.Matches
            .Include(m => m.Team1).ThenInclude(t => t.Players)
            .Include(m => m.Team2).ThenInclude(t => t.Players);

        // if there are any filters, apply them
        if(filterExpression != null)
        {
            query.Where(filterExpression);
        }

        var matches = query.ToListAsync();
        return _mapper.Map<List<MatchDto>>(matches);
    }
}
```

I know that the repository pattern might be suitable for this case, but still, what would be the right way of doing it? Having a `_matchesRepo.Get(interval, team, player, location)` and moving this logic there does not seem to be a very smart approach to be honest...

Can someone give me an advice on this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Of course we could go full enterprise, but what is your goal? If we abide by the 80/20 rule, that says, you can achieve 80% outcome with 20% effort and the remaining 20% outcome with 80% effort - is it worth it? Extract the filtering logic into some sort of Expression builder, so it can be tested seperately and be done with it.

Comment: The actual problem is that I have multiple command handlers like this. By the way, what is an expression builder? I think that's something new for me. I'm going to search for that. If you can share some resources on those, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If those expressions are not the same across handlers, then you really have nothing to extract. I might simplify this one by extracting the expression into a method so you can write `var filterExpression = GetExpression(request);`

Answer (score 1):

`GetMatches` should probably be understood as a *query*, rather than a *command*, based on the example you have provided here.

The key hint being that your implementation is effectively read only - you aren't making changes to your model and saving them in the repository.

Filtering in a query handler is a normal thing to do.

You could probably simplify the design here by encapsulating the construction of the filter expression into another function (separation of concerns / information hiding).